# sharpsvn commit issue "Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file///C:/Testing/repo'"

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

I did create a local repository on my pc. Then I did a svn checkout to access this repository and I can add and commit the files with tortoisesvn.
The repo is **'file///C:/Testing/repo'**
and the local checkout is **"C:\Testing\svn\repo"**
I tried to add and commit some changes to a file with sharpsvn. I get an exceptions:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file///C:/Testing/repo'
```

but when I open tortoisesvn I can access this repo.
My code:

The add function does work, I only get an error with the commit.

```
.
.
.
foreach ( string path in files )
                    {
                        Add(path);
                    }
                    Commit(commitPath, key);
.
.
.
```

```
public bool Commit(string path, string message)
        {
            using ( SvnClient client = new SvnClient() )
            {
                SvnCommitArgs args = new SvnCommitArgs
                {
                    LogMessage = message,
                    ThrowOnError = true,
                    ThrowOnCancel = true
                };

                try
                {
                    return client.Commit(path, args); # <--- Exception
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    if ( e.InnerException != null )
                    {
                        throw new Exception(e.InnerException.Message, e);
                    }

                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

I can see that the files are added in the explorer, but it does not commit. I do not have any authentication set up for the repository, so I have no idea what on the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your TortoiseSVN created a newer repository format than SharpSVN can read. Due to lack of manpower, SharpSVN tends to lag a little bit behind nowadays.

Workarounds:

- Use a local SVN server (SvnServe can be set up easily)
- Create the repository in the older format compatible with SharpSVN (you might need to use the svn.exe command line tool, I'm not sure whether Tortoise provides an UI to select older repository format versions).